# JGraphT avoid loops (Bellman Ford)

Tags: java, loops, graph, jgrapht, bellman-ford

I am using JGraphT for implementing a Bellman Ford shortest path algorithm in Java.
Since there are some edges, that shall be prefered, their edge weight is set to -1.

For example:

A <-> B: 10

A <-> C: 10

C <-> B: -1

B <-> D: 10

So in this case, the Path shall look like A -> C -> B -> D.
The sub-path A->C->B shall be preferred to A->B.

Now here's the problem: the algorithm finds loops between C and B, so that the C->B and B->C paths are added several times (to decrease the total path costs since the weight of B<->C is negative).

Now the question: is it possible to avoid such loops? I didn't find any option in the API. The isAllowingLoops() method of the Graph object returns "false".

Can you give me some hint what to do here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the graph as follows will give you the path you're looking for:

```
DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> g;
g = new DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

g.addVertex("a");
g.addVertex("b");
g.addVertex("c");
g.addVertex("d");

DefaultWeightedEdge edge1 = g.addEdge("a", "b");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge1, 10);
DefaultWeightedEdge edge1a = g.addEdge("b", "a");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge1a, 10);


DefaultWeightedEdge edge2 = g.addEdge("a", "c");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge2, 10);
DefaultWeightedEdge edge2a = g.addEdge("c", "a");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge2a, 10);


DefaultWeightedEdge edge3 = g.addEdge("b", "c");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge3, -1);
DefaultWeightedEdge edge3a = g.addEdge("c", "b");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge3a, -1);


DefaultWeightedEdge edge4 = g.addEdge("b", "d");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge4, 10);
DefaultWeightedEdge edge4a = g.addEdge("d", "b");
g.setEdgeWeight(edge4a, 10);


List<DefaultWeightedEdge> path = BellmanFordShortestPath.findPathBetween(g, "a", "d");
System.out.println(path);
```

The above will output:

```
[(a : c), (c : b), (b : d)]
```